# Stability issues with dual screen and Nvidia card on Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu, i915

I bought a laptop ([HP Zbook](https://www.hp.com/gb-en/shop/list.aspx?fc_sb_zbook=1&sel=NTB)) with integrated Nvidia GPU (RTX A500) to be able to do Deep Learning directly on the Laptop.

I noticed that TensorFlow can only use Nvidia CUDA drivers when you are on Linux (I did not succeed to make it work on Windows).

It works well, except that when I use dual screen display, my PC freezes randomly on Linux. I also use Windows, I have dual boot, the PC never freezes on Windows.

The PC does not freeze either when I do not use the second monitor or when the GPU acceleration does not seem to be active on the second screen.

But if there is a video or a 3D rendering on the second screen, this is when the problem occurs...

I suspect an issue between the integrated Intel display graphics and the Nvidia driver. Both seem to be active :

```
lsmod | grep video

video 73728 2 i915,nvidia_modeset
```

I have many errors in the system log :

```
[ 584.150398] NVRM rmapiAllocWithSecInfo: RMAPI_GPU_LOCK_INTERNAL alloc requested without holding the RMAPI lock

[ 584.151681] NVRM rmapiAllocWithSecInfo: RMAPI_GPU_LOCK_INTERNAL alloc requested without holding the RMAPI lock

[ 584.152980] NVRM rmapiAllocWithSecInfo: RMAPI_GPU_LOCK_INTERNAL alloc requested without holding the RMAPI lock

[ 584.154224] NVRM rmapiAllocWithSecInfo: RMAPI_GPU_LOCK_INTERNAL alloc requested without holding the RMAPI lock

[ 584.155449] NVRM rmapiAllocWithSecInfo: RMAPI_GPU_LOCK_INTERNAL alloc requested without holding the RMAPI lock

[ 584.156709] NVRM rmapiAllocWithSecInfo: RMAPI_GPU_LOCK_INTERNAL alloc requested without holding the RMAPI lock

[ 584.157921] NVRM rmapiAllocWithSecInfo: RMAPI_GPU_LOCK_INTERNAL alloc requested without holding the RMAPI lock

[ 584.159135] NVRM rmapiAllocWithSecInfo: RMAPI_GPU_LOCK_INTERNAL alloc requested without holding the RMAPI lock
```

I suspect a conflict between NVIDIA driver and Intel driver accessing the video memory.

I tried to disable the i915 Intel module but it does not seem possible, both seem to be used simulaneously for display.